# Connect finger print via php

Tags: php, fingerprint, fsockopen

i try to connect finger print to php, but this error message appears:

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 192.168.1.102:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )

here is my code

```
<?
$IP=$_GET["ip"];
$Key=$_GET["key"];
if($IP=="") $IP="192.168.1.201";
if($Key=="") $Key="0";
?>

<form action="tarik-data.php">
IP Address: <input type="Text" name="ip" value="<?=$IP?>" size=15><BR>
Comm Key: <input type="Text" name="key" size="5" value="<?=$Key?>"><BR><BR>

<input type="Submit" value="Download">
</form>
<BR>

<?
if($_GET["ip"]!=""){?>
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
    <tr align="center">
        <td><B>UserID</B></td>
        <td width="200"><B>Tanggal & Jam</B></td>
        <td><B>Verifikasi</B></td>
        <td><B>Status</B></td>
    </tr>
    <?
    $Connect = fsockopen($IP, "80", $errno, $errstr, 1);
    if($Connect){
        $soap_request="<GetAttLog><ArgComKey xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">".$Key."</ArgComKey><Arg><PIN xsi:type=\"xsd:integer\">All</PIN></Arg></GetAttLog>";
        $newLine="\r\n";
        fputs($Connect, "POST /iWsService HTTP/1.0".$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, "Content-Type: text/xml".$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, "Content-Length: ".strlen($soap_request).$newLine.$newLine);
        fputs($Connect, $soap_request.$newLine);
        $buffer="";
        while($Response=fgets($Connect, 1024)){
            $buffer=$buffer.$Response;
        }
    }else echo "Koneksi Gagal";

    include("parse.php");
    $buffer=Parse_Data($buffer,"<GetAttLogResponse>","</GetAttLogResponse>");
    $buffer=explode("\r\n",$buffer);
    for($a=0;$a<count($buffer);$a++){
        $data=Parse_Data($buffer[$a],"<Row>","</Row>");
        $PIN=Parse_Data($data,"<PIN>","</PIN>");
        $DateTime=Parse_Data($data,"<DateTime>","</DateTime>");
        $Verified=Parse_Data($data,"<Verified>","</Verified>");
        $Status=Parse_Data($data,"<Status>","</Status>");
    ?>
    <tr align="center">
            <td><?echo $PIN?></td>
            <td><?=$DateTime?></td>
            <td><?=$Verified?></td>
            <td><?=$Status?></td>
        </tr>
    <?}?>
    </table>
<?}?>
```

please help me, why i cant connect php to fingerprint ?

**UPDATE**

I can ping on 192.168.1.102, but i cant call it from php.

Comment: Is there a service listening to port 80 on 192.168.1.102?  The error you got suggests that your code is working fine ... but you're knocking on the door and no-one is home.

Comment: @Ragdata check my update. I can ping on 192.168.1.102, but i cant call it from php.

Comment: Likely then you don't have anything listening on port 80 on that machine - or port 80 has been firewalled and is not accessible from the local network.

Comment: @Ragdata but why ? is there any problem with my FP ? i try with desktop software, its fine.

Comment: Are we talking about the X100-C here?

Comment: @Ragdata no. We are talking about x104 sir.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the 104 has a built-in webserver.  But, if you're sure it does, make sure that you're on the same subnet as your fingerprint device.  So, if the device is on 192.168.1.102, then you need to be on 192.168.1.xxx ...

Comment: @Ragdata they give me the php script to connect it in the CD package, so i think it can be build with php. My IP is 192.168.1.100, and my FP ip is 192.168.1.102 sir.

Comment: Really not sure what's going on.  Your PHP is fine - no problem there.  Perhaps double-check the configuration and make sure that web access is enabled on the device (I'm not familiar with it).

Comment: @Ragdata thanks for your help rag. I just get confirmed from the shop that x104 doesn't support PHP soap.

Comment: try the port 4370 instead of 80

Answer (score 1):

Your fingerprint may not support web service

Check with your browser, by input 192.168.1.102 in address bar